# Checkbox checked state in Angular 10

Tags: html, angular

I am using Angular 10. I have a checkbox in my html file. In my typescript file I want to see if the checkbox is checked or not and perform some action accordingly. Is there a way to get the checked state of the checkbox like true if it is checked and false otherwise? TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using Template Form or Reactive Form,

```
<input type="checkbox" (change)="changeEvent($event.target.checked)">
```

For Template Forms,

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]='checked' (ngModelChange)="changeEvent()">
```

For reactive forms,

```
<input type="checkbox" formControlName='check'>

this.form.get('check').valueChanges
.subscribe((check)=> this.changeEvent())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use change event to check the state

```
<input type="checkbox" (change)="onSelect($event.target.checked)">


onSelect(state:boolean) {
     console.log("Is Checked? ", state)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, we have two ways of checking the state of the checkbox:

1. Use the library for angular, Ex: Material UI: https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/examples or different libraries.
2. Use two-way binding of angular [(ngModel)] ="checked" on the HTML template

Answer (score 0):

you can use two-way binding like this

html

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="checked">
```

ts

```
checked = false;
```